# Method Local Inner Class Member scope access

Tags: java, oop, scope

How do I access the method variable having the same name as the inner class member instance or method local variable of the inner class?

```
    class A{
       int a = 10;     //1

       public void someMethodA(){
       final int a = 20;     //2

       class B{
       int a = 30;     //3

        public void someMethodB(){
        int a = 40;     //4

        System.out.println("a = "+a);  //access 4
        System.out.println("a = "+this.a);   //access 3
        System.out.println("a = "+A.this.a);    //access 1
        System.out.println(?????);     //how do I access value of a i.e 2

       }
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: that code will never output those statements, but it does compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't do that. The reason being, the variable `a` in position *2* is a local variable, which can only be accessed with it's simple name, in the enclosing scope. From [JLS §6.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1), exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) can only be referred to using a simple name (§6.2), not a qualified name (§6.6).

Now, this clears that you can only access that variable with just `a`. But, you have another variable in method local class `B` which shadows that local variable `a` in position *2*, which is again shadowed by local variable in position *4*.

Now in print statement, `a` would access the variable from nearmost enclosing scope, that is local variable at position *4*. If you remove that variable, it will print the variable at position *3*. And then if you remove it, it will print the variable at position *2*.

So, the point is, there is no way to access the local variable `a` at position *2*, because that is shadowed.

Comment: Well yes you are right, because I had tried this code, but just wanted know if there was a way to doing it, since I'm new to this, most twisted questions really makes me mad, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

that code will never output those statements, here is an example [from Sun](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) that should explain things :

```
    public class ShadowTest {
    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, that code will not give those outputs? That will give.

Comment: your code is simple member inner class, my code required accessing the local variable in method local class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you actually mean, but you access a class member with the same name as a local variable with the same name like this:

```
public class A
{
   int a = 10;

   public void someMethodA()
   {
       int a = 5;
       this.a = 20; //change the member a from 10 to 20
      a = 30; // changes the local variable, which is only known in this method to 30
   }
}
```

Typically this pattern is used in constructors, to name the params the same as member variables, for example:

```
class Foo
{
    private int bar = 10;
    private string fooBar = 20;

    public Foo(int bar, string fooBar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }
}
```